# IE 8 bug? Elements snapping into place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble with my CSS on my page in IE 8. I have a text field floated to the left, a 'next' button floated to the right, and underneath I have some text in a seperate div.

```
            <div id="code_bit">
            <h2>Enter your 16 digit code</h2>
            <input type="text" name="activation_code" id="activation_code" value="<% $activation_code | h %>" size="16" />
            <input id="next_button" type="button" name="signup" value="Next" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
            </div>
<div id="bottom_bit">
    <div id="service_highlights">
        Some text
    </div>

#bottom_bit {
    width: 616px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 30px 215px;
}
#bottom_bit #service_highlights {
    padding: 15px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    border-top: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

signup_bit input {
    color: #000;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 2px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
#signup_bit #info{
    width: 350px;   

    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
}
#signup_bit #activation_code {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 290px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 3px;
}
#signup_bit #next_button {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #63a8d8;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

As you can see, the two elements have been floated. What happens is, when you first view this page, the text underneath the form elements, is wrapped in between the form elements, and then after a few seconds, it snaps into the place it should be.

Are there any IE 8 bugs that can workaround this? I've tried clearing the floats, and some of the other obvious ones with no luck.

Hope you can help, and sorry for the long code,

Snakespan

Comment: can you mock it up in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need is a [*clearing element*](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) below your two floated elements. You had also pasted some invalid CSS, so I've fixed it to match your HTML.

```
<div id="code_bit">...</div>

<br style="display: block; clear: both;" />

<div id="bottom_bit">...</div>
```

A working example can be seen at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kTyaj/

Comment: Hi, which part of the CSS did you update? i can't see any amendments compared to my CSS. Thanks for the help btw, it seemed to help some of the problem but not all, though I have a feeling the changed CSS may solve it.

Comment: Your original CSS referenced HTML elements (`#signup_bit`) that didn't exist in your code sample. You also had a declaration that wasn't valid (`signup_bit input`) -- note the missing `#`. I updated the CSS in the jsFiddle to match the HTML provided in your question.

Comment: ok thank you, I'm still stuck for the solution of this problem but I'm pretty sure I'll have to find a solution myself as I use mangle and mason. Your solution has helped me so far anyway, it still snaps a few pixels so I'll have to just keep trying I guess.

Comment: The "snapping" of pixels you describe is quite likely beyond the scope of the code snippet you posted here. Good luck!

Comment: I managed to fix it after, my javascript was removing a class that positioned the buttons relatively, so I created a new class that floated the same div to the left, and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Nice detective work pinpointing the issue and fixing the problem :)